# How to handle Polylists with multiple inputs from same source

Tags: collada

I found following data in a Collada file from "Newtek LightWave CORE v1.0":

```
<polylist count="2" material="side-zenith_1">
    <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#z1-ext_01_vertices"/>
    <input offset="1" semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#side-zenith" set="0"/>
    <input offset="2" semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#side-zenith" set="1"/>
    <input offset="3" semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#side-zenith" set="2"/>
    <input offset="4" semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#side-zenith" set="3"/>
    <vcount>281 24 </vcount>
    <p>4758 1 1 1 1 4759 ... 4857 279 279 279 279 </p>
</polylist>
```

The problem with this data is that it uses the same source for all TEXCOORD inputs. I wonder what this actually means. So how should i handle this situation during import ? Unfortunately the Collada 1.4.1 specification does not document this case.

- Is this 4 different UV Maps which just happen to use the same UV coordinates ? Does this make sense at all ? If that's it, then where do i find the ids (names) of the 4 UV Maps ?
- Is it just one single UV map with 4 sections ? So it could be treated as 4 partial inputs ? Then i could name the UV map "side-zenith" and collect the data from the 4 inputs into this single UV map...
- Or is this faulty data and should be reported as violation ?

This question is related to a Bug in Blender: https://developer.blender.org/T38482

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](http://collada.org/public_forum/showthread.php/908-A-few-questions-about-lt-input-gt-and-sets) has some answers relating to your question.

Since you mention Blender and I was working with Blender when I ran across this myself exporting Collada files I'll share a little more about my experience with Blender and Collada.

> The way I interpret all those TEXCOORD inputs is that you have 4 sets
>   of UVs that apply to your mesh but since they use the same source it's
>   just redundant mappings. They are probably defined somewhere in your
>   authoring tool (the mappings -- that is).

What Blender does is that it manages multiple sets of UV data in UV maps.

[image: Multiple UV maps]

I had two UV maps and I was not even aware that I had made a second.

[image: Remove UV map]

*More information about managing Blender UV maps can be found [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Layout_Management).*

After I removed that UV map, my Collada export from Blender no longer has multiple UV maps. So there's now only a single TEXCOORD set. If it helps, think of multiple TEXCOORD inputs as multiple sets of UV maps.